# tvOS: Creating UICollectionViewCell effect like main screen

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I'm using UICollectionViewCell for tvOS, each cell contains an image, which I could get it to have some sort of parallax effect using `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` property of `UIImageView`. But I wanted to know how I can make it look like the tvOS home screen.

Desire final result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. `Clip Sub Views` should be disabled in `UIImageView` otherwise parallax effect will not work properly. However collection view cell's clip Sub Views can be (must be, in my case) enabled.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/

- in code:

  `[cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];`
- in interface builder:

[image]